# Taxonomy + post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I'm quite lost with taxonomies and custom post type.

- I have a taxonomy -> auteur
- I have custom_post-type -> citation (quote in french).

I just want list all citations (quote) from an auteur (auteur = taxonomy) with a permalink structure like this :

```
www.myblogname.com/citation/auteur_name/
```

or

```
www.myblogname.com/auteur_name/citation/
```

or

```
www.myblogname.com/auteur/auteur_name/citation/
```

( in fact the easiest way).

what are the steps to do this job (and what is the template page to modify).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how did you set the post type and the taxonomy, but by default I think you're supposed to see all quotes from an author through `myblogname.com/the-author-name`.

If you want to place static words such *auteur* or *citation* in the link, then this is related to how you set the options for creating the post type and/or the taxonomy. ([register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)).

Note: you can't use `author` (in english) because this slug already exists in WordPress (See [Reserved terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms)).

About theme files, when you view a quotes list from an author (a taxonomy in this case), your theme uses `taxonomy.php` file, you can create this file if doesn't exists, see [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
$args = array(           
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'citation/auteur' )
        );
register_taxonomy('auteur','citation',$args);
```

When you do that you can list and filter your citations by auteurs.
Just type in the address bar http://yoursite.com/citation/auteur/auter_name.
But remember that the "autor_name" have to be a slug.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the query below for this issue.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'my_custom_post_type',
'slug'                   => 'citation/auteur',
'post_status'            => 'publish',
'author_name'            => 'author_name',
'order'                  => 'DESC',
);

 // The Query
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    // do something
}
} else {
 // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

Please replace your post type, author name & others with default options.

Comment: There is no parameter slug for WP_Query, so not sure what you are trying to achieve here.. Besides this isn't exactly addressing the issue.